# Loop through a list of row numbers using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, xlrd

I have a list of row numbers and I want to loop through that list using xlrd python module to look into those rows and column 3 and save the value from those cells in a new variable.

Here is what I have so far:

```
rows_exceptions_file_final = [ 2, 5, 6 , 8, 11, 15 ]

rows_string = []

for i in rows_exceptions_file_final:
    rows_string.append(sheet2.cell_value( i , 3))
```

The exception I am getting is:

> cell_value
>       return self._cell_values[rowx][colx] IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are you sure, that the counting internally doesn't start from zero? Try `(i-1, 2)` as the argument

Comment: Nope! Still the same exception unfortunately.

Comment: Put this: `print('row:{}'.format(i)` befor `rows_string.append(...` to show the Row Number which is failing. Then compare with your Worksheet if this Row with 3 Columns exists.

Comment: I was I adding + 1 to every number in the list because enumerate function I used before and enumerate starts from 0 and my rows start from 1.But after removing that add +1 number everything works now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the columns and rows start with index 0.

FYI: you code could be improved to something like:

```py
# row and column index start with 0
rows_exceptions_file_final = [1, 4, 5, 7, 10, 14 ]

col_nb4 = sheet2.col_values(3, 0)
rows_string = [v for i, v in enumerate(col_nb4) if i in row_exceptions_file_final]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was I adding + 1 to every number in the list because enumerate function I used before. Since enumerate starts from 0 and my rows start from 1, but after removing that +1 function everything works fine with the code in the question.